# Transform a column into a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently looking for a way to transform a single column into a table.

Here's an example:

[image]

My plan is to transform this into

[image]

I'm currently using this formula `INDIRECT(ADDRESS((ROW($A1)-1)*2+COLUMN(A1);1))`
which output this result.

[image]

And then i copy paste using the transpose function.

So i would like to know if there is a way to make it work better and easier?

Thank

Comment: What is the problem with current solution? You have to do it many times?

Comment: You could use VBA to loop the through the data and start a new column every N rows (where N is some constant that you specify).

Comment: Yeah the problem is that i have to use my formula, copy paste value ,and then copy paste using transpose, so i find it a bit too tricky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this specific case, assuming that your data is in `Sheet1!A1:A8` use this in Cell `A1` on another sheet:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$8,(COLUMN()*2-1)+(ROW()-1),1)`

and the drag to `B1:D1` and then to `A2:D2`